# I want to receive attachments in me email from the form

Tags: php, html

I've created a career form for a website, i want people to upload resumes and i receive it in my mail, i have done some sort of things where i recieve submitted data from text box and select box but i am unable to receive attachments, please help me to receive the attachments in my mail here is my form and php code :

```
<form method="post" action="careermail.php">
            <table border="0">
            <tr><td class="text">Name</td></tr>
             <tr><td>
            <input class="txtbox" type="text" name="Name" placeholder="Your Name" required="required" /></td></tr>
             <tr><td class="text">Email</td></tr>
            <tr><td><input class="txtbox" type="email" name="Email" placeholder="Your Email" required="required" /></td></tr>
            <tr><td class="text">Role</td></tr>
           <tr><td><select class="slbox" name="Role">
  <option value="development">Development</option>
  <option value="designing">Designing</option>
  <option value="testing">Testing</option>
  <option value="marketing">Marketing</option>
</select></td></tr>
<tr><td class="text">Upload your resume</td></tr>
<tr><td><input class="file" type="file" name="file" size="40"><br /></td></tr>     
<tr><td style="text-align:right;"> <input class="submit" type="Submit" value="Submit" placeholder="Your Email" /></td></tr>
            </table>
            </form>




<script type="text/javascript"> 
    window.alert("Thank you! We will get back to you shortly."); 
window.location.replace("career.html");
  </script> 



<?php

// VALUES FROM THE FORM

$name      = $_REQUEST['Name'];
$email     = $_REQUEST['Email'];
$role = $_REQUEST['Role'];
$File = $_REQUEST['File'];



$fields = array();
$fields{"Name"} = "Name";
$fields{"Email"} = "Email";
$fields{"Role"} = "Role";
$fields{"File"} = "Message";

// CREATE THE EMAIL

$headers    = "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1\n";

$headers    = "From: $name $email <$email>\n";

$recipient  = "info@appsysinfotech.com";

$subject    = "Career Form";

$message    = "A message has been sent from: \n\n"; foreach($fields as $a => $b){ $message .= sprintf("%20s: %s\n",$b,$_REQUEST[$a]); }

// SEND THE EMAIL TO YOU

mail($recipient, $subject, $message, $headers);

?>
```

Comment: You're not sending the attachment when you call the `mail` method. You need to either pass it to some overload of the method, or use a different method.

Comment: where have you included the file as an attachment?

Comment: take a look at the following link http://webcheatsheet.com/PHP/send_email_text_html_attachment.php may help

Comment: Do i need to change the code? what if i pass that parameter in mail function?

Comment: @ShahilM You have a dot missing in `$headers = "From: $name $email <$email>\n";` and needs to be concatenated from your previous header. You'll need to fix that first before trying anything else. Otherwise, it will fail.

Comment: that is a working code but i dont recieve only the attachments

Comment: @ShahilM You mean to tell me that you're receiving HTML email as well as seeing/getting the `From:` ? impossible.

Comment: @ Fred : i get data filled in the text box and select box but not attachment.

Answer (score 0):

Please go through the following link. It will explain you that how to attach a file in your mail using php-

[PHP: Sending Email (Text/HTML/Attachments)](http://webcheatsheet.com/PHP/send_email_text_html_attachment.php)

Comment: Could you please get me done with this and please do explain me the code too. i need to submit this within 4 hours.your help would be invaluable